# Not able to see textbox while hovering over data points

Tags: r, plotly

In reference to [this](https://d4tagirl.com/2017/05/how-to-deal-with-ggplotly-huge-maps).

```
 g <- list(showframe = FALSE,
      coastlinecolor = toRGB("white"),
      showland = TRUE,
      landcolor = toRGB("gray80"),
      showcountries = TRUE,
      countrycolor = toRGB("white"),
      countrywidth = 0.2,
      projection = list(type = 'Mercator'))

plot_geo(New_A_loc,
     marker = list(color = toRGB("purple"),
                   opacity = 0.5,
                   line = list(color = toRGB("purple"),
                               width = 0.5))) %>%
  add_markers(
     data = New_A_loc, x = ~Long, y = ~Lat,
     hoverinfo = "text",text = ~City, alpha = 0.5
      ) %>%
 layout(geo = g)
```

[Full code with data](https://github.com/Arjitkp/New/blob/master/New_2.Rmd).The issue I am facing is, I am not able to view the text box which appears as I move my mouse over data points. I used the same way in which the above blogger used, but I am not able to achieve the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can skip the `add_markers` section and put everything in your `plot_geo` statement.

```
plot_geo(New_A_loc, 
         lat = ~Lat, 
         lon = ~Long,
         text = ~City,
         mode='markers',
         marker = list(color = toRGB("purple"),
                       opacity = 0.5,
                       line = list(color = toRGB("purple"),
                                   width = 0.5))
        ) %>%
  layout(geo = g)
```

[image]